# Using Keycloak behind a reverse proxy: Could not open Admin loginpage because mixed Content

Tags: ssl, https, openshift, keycloak, kong

so I have a problem getting keycloak 3.2.1 to work behind kong (0.10.3), a reverse proxy based on nginx.

Scenario is:

I call keycloak via my gateway-route via `https://{gateway}/auth` and it shows me the entrypoint with keycloak logo, link to admin console etc. - so far so good.

But when clicking on administration console -> calling `https://{gateway}/auth/admin/master/console/` , keycloak tries to load its css/js via http (see screenie below), which my browser blocks because mixed content.

I searched around and found this thread: [keycloak apache server configuration with 'Mixed Content' problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35169503/keycloak-apache-server-configuration-with-mixed-content-problems) which lead to this github repo: https://github.com/dukecon/keycloak_postgres_https

From there on, I tried to integrate its' cli into my dockerfile with success (did not change the files' contents, just copied them into my repo and add/run them from dockerfile). This is my dockerfile right now:

```
FROM jboss/keycloak-postgres:3.2.1.Final

USER root

ADD config.sh /tmp/
ADD batch.cli /tmp/

RUN bash /tmp/config.sh

#Give correct permissions when used in an OpenShift environment.
RUN chown -R jboss:0 $JBOSS_HOME/standalone && \
    chmod -R g+rw $JBOSS_HOME/standalone

USER jboss
EXPOSE 8080
```

Sadly, my problem still exists:
[image: error]

So I am out of ideas for now and hope you could help me out:

- How do I tell keycloak to call its' css-files via https here?
- do I have to change something in the cli script?

Here's the content of the script:

config.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

set -e

JBOSS_HOME=/opt/jboss/keycloak
JBOSS_CLI=$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh
JBOSS_MODE=${1:-"standalone"}
JBOSS_CONFIG=${2:-"$JBOSS_MODE.xml"}

echo "==> Executing..."
cd /tmp

$JBOSS_CLI --file=`dirname "$0"`/batch.cli

# cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34494022/permissions-error-when-using-cli-in-jboss-wildfly-and-docker
/bin/rm -rf ${JBOSS_HOME}/${JBOSS_MODE}/configuration/${JBOSS_MODE}_xml_history/current
```

and batch.cli:

```
embed-server --std-out=echo

# http://keycloak.github.io/docs/userguide/keycloak-server/html/server-installation.html
# 3.2.7.2. Enable SSL on a Reverse Proxy
# First add proxy-address-forwarding and redirect-socket to the http-listener element.
# Then add a new socket-binding element to the socket-binding-group element.

batch

/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/http-listener=default:write-attribute(name=proxy-address-forwarding,value=true)

/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/http-listener=default:write-attribute(name=redirect-socket,value=proxy-https)

/socket-binding-group=standard-sockets/socket-binding=proxy-https:add(port=443)

run-batch

stop-embedded-server
```

It may be of interest too, that kong is deployed on openshift with a route using a redirect from http to https ( "insecureEdgeTerminationPolicy": "Redirect" ).

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? Is there a working example I can take a look of?

Comment: I faced the same with Keycloak 15.0.6 and got it resolved by adding `proxy-address-forwarding="true"` to default http-listener in standalone-ha.xml

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This sounds somehow like a duplicate of [Keycloak Docker behind loadbalancer with https fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068266/keycloak-docker-behind-loadbalancer-with-https-fails)

Set the request headers `X-Forwarded-For` and `X-Forwarded-Proto` in *nginx*. Then you have to configure Keycloak (Wildfly, Undertow) to work together with the SSL terminating reverse proxy (aka load balancer). See http://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/index.html#_setting-up-a-load-balancer-or-proxy for a detailed description.

The point is that *nginx* is terminating SSL and is forwarding the requests to *Keycloak* as pure *http*. Therefore *Keycloak/Wildfly* must be told that the incoming *http* requests from *nginx* must be handled like they were *https*.

Comment: i'll check kong/nginx and accept the answer when I am sure (not my workbench atm, so it will require some time). Thanks so far!

Comment: For anyone stuck in the same situation, i'll also let this hint here: Apart from the things Boomer described (actually, kong sends the proper headers per default), we had a problem with our openshift service, which was called via 8080. the standard port binding for 8080 in kc is http, so kc served http. We changed our openshift config to use 8443, et voila. worked. :)

Comment: Somewhat unrelated question, how does Keycloak resolve its base url? We have a Keycloak istance with a public and private ip address and the `iss` field of the JWT bearer token (which is the realm url) changes accordingly, i.e. if we hit the auth endpoint from public address the `iss` field is `public-ip/realms/master` and from private ip address it's `private-ip/realms/master`. Is this some HTTP magic or a Kycloak config? Docs mention setting up reverse proxy but this is a different case I suppose.

Comment: For newcomers arriving here after trying everything in the docs and all the solutions on stackoverflow and still having problems with mixed content: Setting the [KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61502091/385571) environment variable was that finally fixed it for me

Answer (score 34):

Add the `X-Forwarded-For` and `X-Forwarded-Proto` headers (as Boomer said) in all upstream load balancers and make sure those reach Keycloak server.
`X-Forwarded-For` should be the domain of your Keycloak which routes to the LB and `X-Forwarded-Proto` should be the protocol (most of the cases https).

As a final step you need to modify `standalone.xml` or `standalone-ha.xml` file and add the `proxy-address-forwarding="true"` attribute to `<http-listener>` element under `<server>`.

If you are using Docker you can use `PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING` environment var from the original Keycloak container to set this attribute.

Comment: any idea on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48513451/keycloak-with-nginx-proxy-server-not-authenticating-rest-api?noredirect=1#comment84046838_48513451?

Answer (score 12):

If you're using Keycloak.X (Quarkus version of Keycloak), then those solutions will not work.

You have to set environment variable `KC_PROXY=edge` (as per https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-community/blob/master/design/keycloak.x/configuration.md).

Answer (score 11):

To elaborate on the reply from @MattBianco. In modern Keycloak variables you need to set KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL to https:///auth. Using docker you can set this as an environment variable e.g. KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL=https://auth.foo.com/auth

Comment: depends on the image definition.. bitnami for example has another image : https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-keycloak

Answer (score 7):

I have the same problem with you, now it fixed， This is my method.

First, I setup reverse proxy with cloak at a clean env, confirm that the proxy and cloak was configured rightly.

Next, with test and gusess, I found when setup keycloak use the image you pull from dockerhub whith docker. There is some difference set it up with binary on server, from the standalone.xml, you will find the key point is this 2:

**1. You should set PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true for docker env.**

**2. You should set jboss.https.port 443   for docker env.**

If your standalone.xml also configured rightly, you will get it work for admin page.
Good lucks ;)

Comment: Setting those 2 env variables in `docker-compose` solved the problem for me. No need to edit the `standalone.xml` file.

Comment: For newcomers (2020) arriving here after trying everything in the docs and all the solutions on stackoverflow and still having problems with mixed content: Setting the [KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61502091/385571) environment variable was that finally fixed it for me

Comment: Thank you @MattBianco! You saved my day/night. Actually, it not only worked, but you also have described the whole scene perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

**Two tips :**

If you use a `docker-compose.yml`, add the following env variable to the keycloak container:

```
environment:
  PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: "true"
```

Restart the stack, check if the variable is there (sometimes you have to restart several times the container)

```
docker-compose exec keycloak bash -c 'echo $PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING'
```

If you use an Apache container as a proxy (with mod_proxy) you should add **manually** the X-Forwarded-Proto and X-Forwarded-Port headers:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

# Proxy pass for keycloak
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName auth.myproject_url.tld
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.key
    <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
        SSLProxyEngine on
        <Location "/">
            ProxyPass  "http://keycloak:8080/"
            ProxyPassReverse "http://keycloak:8080/"
            RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
            RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
            #  ProxyPreserveHost On
        </Location>
    </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

After much struggle I found alternative solution using `X-Forwarded-Host` in addition to other headers. This is undocumented however it works, and seems to be working quite long time ago already. Check this pull request https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/pull/5593

Keycloak documentation at https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation mentions that for proxy forwarding you need to set `PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING`=true as docker arg plus `X-Forwarded-For`, `X-Forwarded-Proto` and original `Host` (host of internet facing proxy in my case).

But setting original `Host` was not possible in my case, because I'm hosting Keycloak in Azure app service. Actually the main issue it was not working because proxy sent requests with keycloak internal `Host` header, which is the only way it will work in my case.

Azure app gateway is using `X-ORIGINAL-HOST`, but `X-Forwarded-Host` seems to be more widely used header for original host name. I've tried setting X-Forwarded-Host at my proxy and finally it worked, although this approach is not mentioned in documentation. Check also this discussion https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/x-forwarded-host-proxy-header-support/10730

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue in keycloak v23.0.x

I was able to resolve the issue by setting the below config in nginx

```
location /auth/ {
          proxy_pass          http://localhost:8080/auth/;
          proxy_set_header    Host               $host;
          proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For    $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto  https;
        }
```

And the below ENV was configured for keycloak

```
- KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH=/auth
- KC_PROXY=edge
- KC_HOSTNAME_URL=https://domain-name/auth
```

My infra was set like below,

Load Balancer (ALB) -> nginx -> keycloak

Load Balancer takes care of the SSL and the communication from ALB to nginx is over HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar error whilst using quay.io/keycloak/keycloak docker container in my local environment and nginx reverse proxy, for testing purposes. I used TLS up to proxy where it was terminated, so the solution for me was to add a "--proxy edge" parameter to the command.

Here is a sample from the compose.yml file:

```yaml
services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:latest
    ports:
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./nginx-proxy/certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
    expose:
      - 8080
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: >-
        keycloak.example.org
      VIRTUAL_PORT: 8080
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: "admin"
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: "admin"
      KC_HOSTNAME: keycloak.example.org
    volumes:
      - ./keycloak/data:/opt/keycloak/data
    command: start-dev --proxy edge
```

This is also elaborated in the following docs: https://www.keycloak.org/server/reverseproxy