# Keycloak Redirect url with nginx is going to http rather than https

Tags: nginx, jboss

Keycloak is using reverse proxy with nginx configuration to be available in ssl(https).
Now i have deployed .net core aplication in ubuntu.
This application is in http and is using keycloak as openid connect for authentication.

However, when the aplication is hosted in https using nginx, keycloak is showing invalid redirect url instead of login page. 
 Keycloak login url page contains redirect_uri parameter with http instead of https. Please help to resolve
Configuration done in configuration file in nginx for reverse proxy

```
server {

 listen 443  ssl;

 server_name  abc.ctech.com;

 ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/external/wildcard_ctech_com.pem;

 ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/external/private.rsa;


location / {


   proxy_http_version 1.1;

   proxy_set_header Host abc.ctech.com; 

  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;

   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;  

proxy_pass http://172.30.5.28:8001; 


  }

}

#Keycloak Service
server {

  listen 443  ssl;

  server_name  keycloak.ctech.com; 

 ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/external/wildcard_ctech_com.pem;

  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/external/private.rsa;

location = / {

  return 301 https://keycloak.ctech.com/auth;
} 

location /auth {

  proxy_pass http://172.30.5.28:8080/auth;

  proxy_http_version 1.1;

  proxy_set_header Host keycloak.ctech.com;  

  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;

  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I've been fighting with clustered keycloak in docker swarm mode for a long time now.
[Ubunter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59640845/385571) is the same as in the docs, but doing that still didn't fix things for me.

What I had to do to make it work with the current `jboss/keycloak:latest` docker image, (`:9.0.3`) was to use the environment variable **KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL**.

Before adding that, it still kept issuing http URLs to the main `/auth/js/keycloak.js?version=czy98` javascript:

```html
...
    <!-- Libraries not managed by yarn -->
    <script src="/auth/resources/czy98/admin/keycloak/lib/angular/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js"></script>
    <script src="/auth/resources/czy98/admin/keycloak/lib/angular/treeview/angular.treeview.js"></script>
    <script src="/auth/resources/czy98/admin/keycloak/lib/fileupload/angular-file-upload.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/auth/resources/czy98/admin/keycloak/lib/filesaver/FileSaver.js"></script>
    <script src="/auth/resources/czy98/admin/keycloak/lib/ui-ace/min/ace.js"></script>
    <script src="/auth/resources/czy98/admin/keycloak/lib/ui-ace/ui-ace.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://my.server.name.here/auth/js/keycloak.js?version=czy98" type="text/javascript"
></script>

    <script src="/auth/resources/czy98/admin/keycloak/js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/auth/resources/czy98/admin/keycloak/js/controllers/realm.js" type="text/javascript"></scr
ipt>
    <script src="/auth/resources/czy98/admin/keycloak/js/controllers/clients.js" type="text/javascript"></s
cript>
    <script src="/auth/resources/czy98/admin/keycloak/js/controllers/users.js" type="text/javascript"></scr
ipt>
    <script src="/auth/resources/czy98/admin/keycloak/js/controllers/groups.js" type="text/javascript"></sc
ript>
    <script src="/auth/resources/czy98/admin/keycloak/js/controllers/roles.js" type="text/javascript"></scr
ipt>
    <script src="/auth/resources/czy98/admin/keycloak/js/loaders.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/auth/resources/czy98/admin/keycloak/js/services.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
```

It also generated http in the inline javascript:

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var authServerUrl = 'http://my.server.name.here/auth';
        var authUrl = 'http://my.server.name.here/auth';
        var consoleBaseUrl = '/auth/admin/master/console/';
        var resourceUrl = '/auth/resources/czy98/admin/keycloak';
        var masterRealm = 'master';
        var resourceVersion = 'czy98';
    </script>
```

Despite `X-Forwarded-Proto: https` and the other required things in the `standalone-ha.xml`

Comment: thanks, it resolved my problem accessing realm admin console, though still something not correct 100% so if request **without the last slash /** it still returns wrong scheme/port 
`$ curl -I https://<domain>/auth/admin/myrealm/console
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
...
Location: http://<domain>:8000/auth/admin/myrealm/console/`
8000 is the port nginx listens for requests from Network LB.

Answer (score 2):

You need to proxy pass to https://keycloak_address:8443/auth;. Make sure you have that port open. The below code worked for me.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    server_tokens off;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;


    location /auth {
                proxy_pass  https://keycloak_address:8443/auth;
                proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
                proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is a KEYCLOAK file configuration. You should add the follow parameters in ***http_listener***:

```
<http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="proxy-https" proxy-address-forwarding="true" enable-http2="true"/>
```

and add too ***socket-binding-group*** :

```
<socket-binding name="proxy-https" port="443"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you must also add a server block listening on port 80 (http) which returns a permanent (301) redirect to the port 443 (https) version of the same server..

Something like the following... (and that goes for BOTH places)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

So you would need to add a permanent redirect at both places, replacing (of course) *example.com* with your actual server names.

Let us know, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for those who use [jwilder/nginx-proxy](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy) can just let the reverse proxy handle https and just add

```
  - PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true
  - VIRTUAL_HOST= /**domain or subdomain**/
  - VIRTUAL_PORT=8080
```

to your keycloak environment params