# keycloak running on openshift behind F5 fails with https

Tags: keycloak, reverse-proxy, f5

I'm running `keycloak` on openshift while I'm terminating my SSL on <kbd>F5</kbd>.

I set `PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true` and also configured my `F5` to enable `X-Forwarded-For` and `X-Forwarded-Proto` as mentioned [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/index.html#_setting-up-a-load-balancer-or-proxy).

When I click on the admin console, `keycloak` redirects me to an HTTP URL and not an HTTPS one.

I tried

- [Setting Up a Load Balancer or Proxy](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/index.html#_setting-up-a-load-balancer-or-proxy)
- [Using Keycloak behind a reverse proxy: Could not open Admin loginpage because mixed Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47181821/using-keycloak-behind-a-reverse-proxy-could-not-open-admin-loginpage-because-mi)